# Polynomials such that $P(\mathbb{U})\subset \mathbb{U}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

**Question**

> Let $\mathbb{U}$ be the unit circle.
> Find all $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $P(\mathbb{U})\subset \mathbb{U}$.

**My attempt**

My conjecture is that $P=\mu X^d$ for some $d\geqslant 0$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{U}$.
I tried to prove it by contradiction, making a recurrence on the number of monomials in the polynom. Unfortunately it doesn't lead to anything interesting.

Could someone help me ?

NB : It isn't the same the question as [Which polynomials fix the unit circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908353/which-polynomials-fix-the-unit-circle), since $P(x+iy)\neq P(x)+iP(y)$ in general.

Comment: I know it's been marked as a duplicate, but I'm not sure I understand what $P(\mathbb U)$ is supposed to mean when $P$ is a single-variable polynomial and $\mathbb U$ consists of complex numbers (or pairs of real numbers).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Actually it's not a duplicate. And $P(\mathbb{U})=\{P(z),z\in \mathbb{U}\}$.

Comment: @Sit Exactly ! I hope one will reopen the post.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Complex Analysis to deal with this problem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Actually this question doesn't come from any book or course. It's just a question I was asking myself so any solution is ok for me.

Comment: There might be another dupe though, at least by the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233024 . So your conjecture seems to be correct but furthemore $\mu \in \{-1,1\}$ since $P\in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: @math Oh, I see , thanks for the clarification. I wasn't sure it was a duplicate but that's because I hadn't understood what $P(\mathbb U)$ was in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $P(X)= \sum_{j=k}^n a_j X^j$, with $a_k \neq 0$ and $a_n \neq 0$. Then
$$2\pi \overline{a_k}a_n=\int_{0}^{2\pi}P(e^{it})\overline{P(e^{it})}e^{i(n-k)}d=\int_{0}^{2\pi}|P(e^{it})|^2e^{i(n-k)}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(n-k)}dt$$

since $|P(e^{it})|=1$ by hypothesis. Because $a_k \neq 0$ and $a_n \neq 0$, you get that necessarily, $n=k$ and $|a_n|=1$, which implies that
$$\boxed{P(X)=\pm X^n}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's clear and concise.